# can I use java code as a cordova/phonegap plugin?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, intel-xdk, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I am creating a mobile app using intel xkd,angular and cordova. Here we have a java code for one module. so i wanna know, can i integrate the java code into my app like a plugin ?. Because, most of the cordava/phonegap plugin have java file as plugin assets.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use Java Code, as you said correctly, via plugins. Just follow the Cordova docs concererning Cordova Plugins:

[Android Plugins](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/plugin.html)

Comment: NOTE: as long as that Java code can run within the context of an Android Java app you can incorporate it in a plugin (for the Android platform). If you're talking about Java code that is running on a server, that code is not likely to do what you want it to, unless it is pure computational or logic code (e.g., compressing a data file or parsing a file, etc.). For example, if it is Java server code that gets or puts info into a database on a server, it probably won't work 'cause your Java code won't be running on that server, where the database resides...